# including a new file in C++ with eclipse cdt

Tags: c++, eclipse, include, eclipse-cdt

Sorry if this is a duplicated question. 
I have eclipse juno, cdt in ubuntu. A hello world autotools project that works. Now I want to use a function in another file so, I created a one.h and one.cpp and modified the main_hello.cpp:

main_hello.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "one.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
        cout << "Hello World" << endl;
        onehello();
        return 0;
}
```

one.h:

```
#ifndef ONE_H_
#define ONE_H_
void onehello(void);
#endif /* ONE_H_ */
```

one.cpp:

```
#include "one.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void onehello(void) {
        cout << "Hello one" << endl;
}
```

When I build it, I get an "undefined reference to `onehello()". It works if I define the function in one.h instead of one.cpp. 
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to add `one.cpp` as a source file to your `makefile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one.cpp to src/Makefile.am :

It should be the following line in this file:

some_name_SOURCES=main_hello.cpp

So, add one.cpp:

some_name_SOURCES=main_hello.cpp one.cpp

Comment: ok, done that and now I get. No rule to make target 'main_hello.cpp,one.o'. Is there something else I need to change?

Comment: my misprint, space should be instead of comma: some_name_SOURCES=main_hello.cpp one.cpp.